# Improvement of an ACP final picture

Tags: plotting

Here is the final representation of an ACP.

```
a = {{-0.9144680477444371`, 
0.07157996947260341`}, {-0.8778331729519082`, \
-0.46377161540880474`}, {-0.9728685071710951`, -0.2103183933493198`}, \
{-0.12473337074751233`, -0.7769101910058934`}, {0.980649667739876`, \
-0.008829992325873183`}, {0.9745907838505693`, \
-0.15720652884819014`}, {0.6415659253250214`, -0.7263609378053126`}, \
{-0.919046857278794`, -0.3241186160675607`}, {0.1158459109858525`, 
0.8684359354988462`}, {0.6781632942683967`, \
-0.6101489754148182`}};
Show[Graphics[{Red, Circle[], LightYellow, Disk[]}], 
ListPlot[Tooltip[a]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True]
```

which gives

[image: Graphics]

Each point corresponds to a label.

```
b = {"Jean", "Lucien", "Karl", "Leon", "Simone", "Frédérique", 
 "Fleur", "Rose", "Dionisa", "Lauredana"}
```

I wonder how to replace the points by the two or three first letters of the names, and if it is possible to pass the complete name in a Tooltip setting.

Comment: Try with `MapThread`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Graphics[{Red, Circle[], LightYellow, Disk[], Blue}~Join~
  MapThread[Tooltip[Text[StringTake[#1, 2], #2], #1] &, {b, a}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was expecting for. Just the necessity to enlage the background because Si and Fr are not correctly displayed. I use the occasion to ask for a procedural question : I have not found a nice code to make a complete ACP. So I have writen a piece of code largely inspired from a sheet found on the net.   I would be pleased  to transfer it to those who would like to benefit of  it in MSE. Should I ask a question and answer by myself ?

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki just add `PlotRangePadding->0.5` after the list of graphic elements (or whatever value you find aesthetically pleasing).